# White screen after a couple hours?

Tags: fatal-error

I get a white screen **after a couple hours** of my site working fine.

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function of_get_option() in /home/talg/public_html/wp-content/themes/avanter/header.php on line 19

I am still able to access the backend portion of the site.

I have tried to install a theme update blocker but have had no success?

I believe the problem is related to the options framework which the theme is built on. Which is odd because the theme has been working fine for over a year.

> WordPress 4.7.4 running Avanter theme.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the error is coming from the "Avanter" theme. The theme code is trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

That is an issue for your theme's developers to fix with an update to their theme. If you install a 'theme update blocker', you won't get the update.

But, you need to contact the theme developer's support forum via their support page.

Answer (score 0):

The of_get_option function is a part of the Options Framework plugin and is used to retrieve your theme settings. If you are getting the error you should contact the theme developer so they can help you fix the problem.

It is possible this specific theme requires you to install the following plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/ - but it's not installed or active on the site and they didn't add the proper checks in their theme so you are getting an error. If this is a free theme and you can't contact the developer you can try installing the plugin to see if it helps.

Personally though I would recommend switching to a newer theme that makes use of the WordPress customizer ;) Using frameworks like for theme options hasn't been necessary for many years now and it's just added bloat on your site.